# 'Consumes' defaults to 'application/octet-stream' on Spring Boot RequestMapping, null when set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to create a simple Post request handler in Spring Boot that consumes JSON.

```
@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebFormController
{
    @RequestMapping(path="/process-contact-form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> processContact(@RequestBody Form form) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("TEST TEST: Ran");
        return  new ResponseEntity<String>("Thank you for contacting us, we'll respond soon.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

By default, my understanding is this will consume application/json.
However, when I make a request using curl or Postman, I get this response from Spring...

```
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
```

And in Postman I get '415 Unsupported Media Type'.

If I explicitly define the 'consumes' property...

```
@RequestMapping(path="/process-contact-form", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Spring Boot returns this...

```
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '' not supported
```

I've tried setting consumes to "application/json", x-www-form-urlencoded, and plain text and sending those types of requests from Postman, but I get the same results.

I built this off aws-serverless-java-container https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot and I'm running it from the SAM local CLI.

EDIT

I switched logging to DEBUG to get more details...

```
2020-05-08 17:53:40.692 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] s.b.w.s.f.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured for use
2020-05-08 17:53:40.692 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.i.servlet.FilterChainHolder      : Starting REQUEST: filter 0-characterEncodingFilter
2020-05-08 17:53:40.698 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.i.s.AwsProxyHttpServletRequest   : Called set character encoding to UTF-8 on a request without a content type. Character encoding will not be set
2020-05-08 17:53:40.698 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.i.servlet.FilterChainHolder      : Starting REQUEST: filter 2-com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.FilterChainManager$ServletExecutionFilter
2020-05-08 17:53:40.729 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/process-contact-form", parameters={}
2020-05-08 17:53:40.732 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.i.servlet.AwsHttpServletRequest  : Trying to access session. Lambda functions are stateless and should not rely on the session
2020-05-08 17:53:40.758 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.i.s.AwsHttpServletResponse       : Response buffer flushed with 0 bytes, latch=1
2020-05-08 17:53:40.761  WARN 1 --- [           main] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '' not supported]
2020-05-08 17:53:40.761 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 415
2020-05-08 17:53:40.763 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.i.servlet.AwsHttpServletRequest  : Trying to access session. Lambda functions are stateless and should not rely on the session
2020-05-08 17:53:40.768 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.i.servlet.FilterChainHolder      : Executed ERROR: filter 3-com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.FilterChainManager$ServletExecutionFilter
2020-05-08 17:53:40.769 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.i.servlet.FilterChainHolder      : Executed ERROR: filter 3-characterEncodingFilter
2020-05-08 17:53:40.779  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.internal.LambdaContainerHandler  : 127.0.0.1:56893 null- null [08/05/2020:17:53:40Z] "POST /process-contact-form null" 415 - "-" "-" combined
2020-05-08 17:53:40.818 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@c9d82f99 pairs: {POST /2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/807c7e06-86f6-1bd3-1055-78b464604573/response HTTP/1.1: null}{Docker-Lambda-Invoke-Wait: 1588960412475}{Docker-Lambda-Init-End: 1588960420587}{User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_201}{Host: 127.0.0.1:9001}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}{Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded}{Content-Length: 104}
2020-05-08 17:53:40.822 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@6f0129144 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted}{Content-Type: application/json}{Date: Fri, 08 May 2020 17:53:40 GMT}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}
2020-05-08 17:53:40.825 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@18fdb6cf5 pairs: {GET /2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/next HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_201}{Host: 127.0.0.1:9001}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}
```

EDIT

**StreamLambdaHandler**

```
public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("TEST TEST " + inputStream.toString() + " " + outputStream.toString());
        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the correct content-type in Postman? Make sure to select Body -> raw -> JSON (in drop down menu).

Comment: Thanks fram, I did set the content-type in Postman using the raw dropdown. I also double check that its correct in the Headers. I've tried a few different content types from Postman and it doesn't change my results. I've added some more verbose logging to my post.

Comment: Are you able to run your project locally in the standard way and have it process a POST request? If so that would maybe mean that this serverless package has some missing config somewhere between when it receives the request and when it proxies it to your app.

Comment: @fram great advice. I was able to run it locally the standard way. I'll add the code to the StreamLambdaHandler to my post in case that contains clues to what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had some assistance starting the app from scratch, and using different libraries. The annotation looks like this now..

```
@Path("/submit")
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SubmitController {

    private JiraService jira;
    private ConfigurationRepository configurations;

    @Autowired
    public SubmitController(JiraService jira, ConfigurationRepository configurations) {
        this.jira = jira;
        this.configurations = configurations;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/{id}")
    @AnonymousAllowed
    @Produces({APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response submitForm(@PathParam("id") String id, String body) {
        // Stuff
    }
```